How make veins simulator and carla 9.0.15 interact using sumo as connection point
What I'd like to achieve is something similar to this post related to artery simulator: https://github.com/riebl/artery/issues/116
I'm using omnetpp 5.7, sumo 1.9.2, carla 9.0.15 and veins directly downloaded from github.
I started from veins example, added this:
<traci_server>
    <num-clients value="2" />
</traci_server>

to the sumo.cfg in order to make the sumo server expect two clients.
Then I added the client order inside the omnet.ini file.
The problem is that when I launch the script using:
./veins_launchd -vv -c sumo-gui

and then, after connecting the omnetpp client to it, lanch the script to connect the carla client:
python3 run_synchronization.py 
<path_to_sumocgf.sumocfg> --debug -- 
sumo-port <ports_depending_on_sumo_server> --sumo-host 127.0.0.1 --client-order 2

and start the simulation in sumo, it will crash after 3 events.
I was not able to debug because, for some reason when I launch in debbug mode my pc freeze, so I use some print to understand the problem:
Problem with Carla and Veins
while, when I run only the veins example without any other clients, the log is this one:
Veins without other clients
I'm thinking the problem could be that Carla send some message not handled by veins, can someone help me, please?
Thank you!
